# How to implement the `Serde::Deserialize` trait for a generic enum

Tags: rust, serde

Let's consider the following sample generic enum:

```rust
enum Enum<T, U> {
    T(T),
    U(U),
}
```

Implementing the `Serde::Serialize` trait for `Enum` is fairly easy:

```rust
impl<T, U> Serialize for Enum<T, U>
where
    T: Serialize,
    U: Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        match self {
            Enum::T(t) => t.serialize(serializer),
            Enum::U(u) => u.serialize(serializer),
        }
    }
}
```

However I'm having a hard time implementing the `Serde::Deserialize` trait, which should behave as follows:

- If the value can be deserialized as type `T`, then it should return `Enum::T(t)`.
- Otherwise if the value can be deserialized as type `U`, then it should return `Enum::U(u)`.
- Otherwise it should return an error.

This is the closer I could get:

```rust
impl<'de, T, U> Deserialize<'de> for Enum<T, U>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    U: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        if let Ok(t) = T::deserialize(deserializer) {
            Ok(Enum::T(t))
        } else {
            if let Ok(u) = U::deserialize(deserializer) {
                Ok(Enum::U(u))
            } else {
                Err(D::Error::custom("Failed to deserialize Enum"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however I get the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `deserializer`
   --> src\lib.rs:731:47
    |
724 |         fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    |                           ------------ move occurs because `deserializer` has type `D`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
728 |             if let Ok(t) = T::deserialize(deserializer) {
    |                                           ------------ value moved here
...
731 |                 if let Ok(f) = F::deserialize(deserializer) {
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
726 |             D: Deserializer<'de> + std::marker::Copy,
    |                                  +++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

I understand what's happening, but I'm not sure how to fix it (the compiler suggestion is not working either).

Comment: Is your goal to implement this for practice? If not, `#[serde(untagged)]` will do it in a `#[derive(Serialize)]` implementation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm implementing this for a library, so I would like to avoid derived traits. Your comment made me think that maybe I should use `cargo expand` to see what that annotation generates though...

Comment: Why you want to avoid deriving `Deserialize`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, now that you say that... yes actually I don't see any valid reason, so I'll try that path and post here if I find a good solution. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I'm trying to implement this for the `rust-csv` crate, deriving `Deserialize` does not work as expected because I need to customize the deserialization to `String`, see: https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/issues/345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same implementation as my previous answer, but relying on [serde-value](https://crates.io/crates/serde-value) instead of `serde::__private`. Once `serde-value` is stable, it may be included directly in `Serde`, but this seems to be moving rather slow, see:

- https://github.com/arcnmx/serde-value/issues/16
- https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/741

```rust
impl<'de, T, U> Deserialize<'de> for Enum<T, U>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    U: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let value = serde_value::Value::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        if let Ok(t) = T::deserialize(value.clone().into_deserializer()) {
            Ok(Enum::T(t))
        } else if let Ok(u) = U::deserialize(value.into_deserializer()) {
            Ok(Enum::U(u))
        } else {
            Err(D::Error::custom(
                "input data did not match any variant type",
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

After Kevin Reid's comment, I used [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) to review the code produced by `serde_derive` for an untagged enum, and came up with the following implementation:

```rust
impl<'de, T, U> Deserialize<'de> for Enum<T, U>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    U: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let content = serde::__private::de::Content::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let deserializer = serde::__private::de::ContentRefDeserializer::<D::Error>::new(&content);
        if let Ok(t) = T::deserialize(deserializer) {
            Ok(Enum::T(t))
        } else if let Ok(u) = U::deserialize(deserializer) {
            Ok(Enum::U(u))
        } else {
            Err(D::Error::custom(
                "input data did not match any variant type",
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to rely on `serde::__private::de::Content` and `serde::__private::de::ContentRefDeserializer`, which currently are in Serde private API but may become public in the future, see:

- https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/741
- https://github.com/arcnmx/serde-value/issues/16

Comment: Relying on private APIs of a library, any library, is just wrong. Don't do it.

Comment: Please don't do this. This is a good way to have your library randomly start breaking when the private API it relies on inevitably changes.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman @AndersEvensen, can you please post your suggestion? I would not like to depend on `serde-value` which seems unmaintained.